# What's the quickest way to spell check arbitrary text in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, text-editors, spell-check

If I'm using a program that doesn't have its own built-in spell checking, what's the fastest way to spell check a textbox from said program (or my clipboard, assuming I have copied the textbox's content)?

My question specifically relates to Windows 10, as I understand OS X has its own system-wide spell checker.

A couple examples I can think of:

- Copy and paste the contents into Word
- Copy and paste the contents into Google search

Comment: I use word as it has a better spell checker as open source, browser or ispell based tools (at lest for German). If publishing grade spell checking is required there are also commercial spell checkers from the dictionary companies available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not consider the installation and setup time, **installing [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/)** might be a solution for you. Hunspell is the spell checker of LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org, Mozilla Firefox 3 & Thunderbird, Google Chrome, etc. Once you installed it, the [Hunspell tutorial](http://xahlee.info/comp/hunspell_spell_checking.html) may guide you on the command line usage.

**MacGyver-approch:** If you prefer not to install anything new, you could make a simple HTML-page with a text field and use the build-in spell checker of your browser (by opening that HTML-page and pasting your text inside that box).

Answer (score 0):

It is fast in **CudaText** editor:

- Plugins/ Addon Manager/ Install: choose here Spell Checker plugin
- open new tab
- paste your text
- Plugins/ Spell Checker/ Check text with suggestions: it will show red underlines for bad words